# setting normal map at run-time unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

am trying to create a mesh at run time by giving list of points represent a polygon, however everything looks good.

i tried to add material and a base texture to the model works fine.
but when it comes to add normal map nothing happen in the mesh still looking flat.

any ideas what going wrong?
am newbie to unity any help would be thankful.
here is my current code:

```
        GameObject AddPolygon(List<Vector3> points)
    {
        GameObject polygon = new GameObject("Polygon");
        polygon.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        polygon.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        polygon.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = CreateMesh(points);

        // Load the texture
        Texture2D texture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("tex");
        Texture2D normalTexture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("nor");
        Texture2D aoTexture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("ao");
        Texture2D heightTexture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("h");

        // Create a new Material and assign the texture to it
        Material material = new Material(Shader.Find("Universal Render Pipeline/Lit"));
        polygon.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = material;
        material.SetTexture("_BaseMap", texture);
        material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", normalTexture);
        material.SetTexture("_OcclusionMap", aoTexture);
        material.SetTexture("_ParallaxMap", heightTexture);
        return polygon;
    }

    private Mesh CreateMesh(List<Vector3> points)
{
    List<int> tris = new List<int>();
    List<Vector2> uvs = new List<Vector2>();

    // Calculate the bounds of the polygon
    Bounds bounds = new Bounds(points[0], Vector3.zero);
    for (int i = 1; i < points.Count; i++)
    {
        bounds.Encapsulate(points[i]);
    }

    // Define the scale factor for the texture
    float scaleFactor = 16.0f; // Increase this value to repeat the texture more times

    for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
    {
        tris.Add(0);
        tris.Add((i + 1) % points.Count);
        tris.Add((i + 2) % points.Count);

        // Calculate the UV coordinates and scale them
        uvs.Add(new Vector2((points[i].x / bounds.size.x) * scaleFactor, (points[i].z / bounds.size.z) * scaleFactor));
    }

    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh.vertices = points.ToArray();
    mesh.uv = uvs.ToArray();
    mesh.triangles = tris.ToArray();
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    mesh.RecalculateTangents();
    return mesh;
}
```